# Is there a function that strips HTTP response headers?

Tags: java, android, html

**HttpResponse.getEntity().getContent()** returns *everything*... including response headers, javascript code, response body (of course!) etc.

Is there a function that cleans this up and provides *only the response body*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read the data from the InputStream to a buffer. Search for this regex:

```
\r\n\r\n(.*)
```

This will give you the things after the header.

Or you can replace it with an empty string, if you are searching for:

```
^.*?\r\n\r\n
```

Comment: The regex "\r\n\r\n(.*)" doesn't find any matches on a raw HttpResponse.getEntity().getContent() (placed into InputStream of course). Any idea why?

Comment: But "(</head>)(.+)" works. I am going to check now why and what this means.

Comment: I think I found the source of my confusion: The raw HttpResponse.getEntity().getContent() starts with **<!doctype html>** which means it is already the response body. I could be so blind sometimes...

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out patterns using Android with your own method. Pass in the String, and apply pattern filters to remove things you don't want.

```
public String filter(String searchString)
    {
        String content = searchString;
        // Remove the new line characters.
        Pattern newLineChar = Pattern.compile("\n+");
        Matcher mLine = newLineChar.matcher(content);
        while (mLine.find())
            content = mLine.replaceAll("");
        // Return the clean content
        return content;
    }
```

You can get quite complicated with your patterns, and filter pretty much any expression you want. (You may need to use regular expressions etc). The example above replaces a new line (\n) with 0 length string, to remove all of them from the string. You can build up patterns, or you can just iterate through again to remove something else.

You will also need a couple of imports for this to work:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

Comment: I tried your code. I compiles but it doesn't work as expected for some reason. Are you sure there is no error in the code?

Comment: I think I now understand what you meant: You only provided this as an example (for stripping newlines, not response headers). The regex for identifying the entire response header and replacing it with an empty string should be different, right?

Comment: @Regex Rookie, yes this was only an example, and was not an exhaustive approach. The regex will be different yes